# Proving that a family of functions is compact

Tags: complex-analysis, convex-analysis, several-complex-variables

1. Suppose that I'm dealing with a family of complex functions analytic in the right-half plane and that each $f$ has a representation:

$$f(z) = \int^1_{-1} \frac{2z}{(1+ z^2) + t(1 - z^2)} \, d\mu(t),$$

where $d\mu(t)$ is some probability measure. How do I show that such a family is compact?

2. Similarly, let each $f(z_1, z_2)$ be analytic in $\mathbb{C}_+ \times \mathbb{C}_+$.

$$f(z_1, z_2) = \int^1_{-1}\int^1_{-1} \frac{2z_1}{(1+ z_1^2) + t_1(1 - z_1^2)} \frac{2z_2}{(1+ z_2^2) + t_2(1 - z_2^2)} \, d\mu_1(t)\, d\mu_2(t).$$

Do those functions form a compact family?

Comment: Where does convex analysis come in to this? What topology are you using on the functions $f$?

Comment: Ad topology - the one given by uniform convergence on compact subsets.
Ad convexity - probably not much, but since I'm ultimately interesting in applying some results concerning convex functionals on convex compact families of analytic functions, I hoped this might of relevance (Will remove the tag if that's mislabeling.)

Comment: I would start by trying to show that the collection of functions $\{2z/((1+z^2)+t(1-z^2)): t\in [-1,1]\}$ is compact.  Your set is the convex hull of this collection, so the end game should be easy.

Comment: @kimchilover Is it obvious that my set is the convex hull, as opposed to: contained in the convex hull?

Comment: Also, is it straightforward to see that $\{2z/((1+ z^2) + t(1 - z^2)): t \in [-1, 1]\}$ is compact? It would be compact if it was closed and locally uniformly bounded; and it would be l.c.b. if if it was normal, but not sure if this gets me anywhere so far...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are suggestions, not proofs.  (I'm not very familiar with spaces of analytic functions, and am away from reference books now.)

For $t\in [-1,1]$, define $$K(z,t) = \frac{2z}{(1+z^2)+t(1-z^2)}.$$   It is a routine exercise that the map $\mu\mapsto f(z)=\int_{[-1,1]} K(z,t) \mu(dt)$ is a continuous map from the probability measures on $[-1,1]$ (with the weak* topology) into the analytic functions on the right half plane.

At the risk of boring you, here is one way to argue.

One has to check that if $\mu_n\to\mu$ weak* then the corresponding $f_n\to f$ uniformly on compacts.  Let $C$ be a compact subset of the half plane.  Then $K$ is uniformly continuous on $C\times[-1,1]$.  Hence the collection of restrictions $K_t: z\mapsto K(z,t)$ of $K$ obtained by holding $t$ fixed is uniformly continuous: the 2-dimensional modulus of continuity $\omega$ of $K$ serves as a common 1-dimensional modulus of continuity for the  $K_t$. Cover $C$ with finitely many $\delta$-balls, and bound $\|f_n-f\|_C=\sup\{|f_n(z)-f(z)|: z\in C\}$ with a finite sum of differences of integrals, one per ball center,  plus a term $\omega(\delta)$.  The weak* convergence of the $\mu_n$ to $\mu$ shows the differences of the integrals converges to $0$; choice of $\delta$ small enough then forces $\|f_n-f\|_C<\epsilon$ for any desired $\epsilon$.

Then your set is the continuous image of the set of probability measures on $[-1,1]$, which is compact. 
Alternatively, if $f_n$ are elements of your set, corresponding to measure $\mu_n$, there is a weak* convergent subsequence of the $\mu_n$ with limit $\mu$.  Then the foregoing argument shows that the corresponding subsequence of $f_n$ converges as desired.

Similarly for 2.  Or more directly, probably.  Surely the cartesian product of a compact set of functions  of $z_1$ with a compact set of functions of $z_2$ is compact in the space of functions of $(z_1,z_2)$?

In some sense, by using integrals against probability measures $\mu$ you are automatically closing your sets, in  a way you wouldn't if you used finite weighted sums.

Comment: Great, thank you! (I'd welcome any potential reference suggestions, especially concerning $\mu \mapsto f(z)$ being continuous.)

Comment: I have added detail.  The spaces involved are all separable metric spaces, so sequences suffice for compactness checking.  For a general reference on convergence of probability measures, Billingsley's _Convergence of Probability Measures_ is hard to beat.